# Why my tasks only be done in one worker in Spark cluster

Tags: apache-spark

I build a spark cluster with a  master and 2 slaves( one of the slave and master are in same machine).I modify wordcount example so that it can output some message when mapToPair() is called. I submit it to master. But only one worker has output in stdout. Is that mean only one Work do the task? Each of my worker has one core. I alse try to make 1000 slice in textFile() but still not work . How to make both worker do tasks? Do i make some mistake?

```
 SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("ORSIFTask").setMaster("spark://192.168.0.110:7077");
JavaSparkContext ctx = new JavaSparkContext(sparkConf);    
ctx.addJar("/home/hadoop/ont-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar");


JavaRDD<String> lines = ctx.textFile("hdfs://192.168.0.110:9000/features4.data",2).cache();
JavaRDD<String> words = lines.flatMap(new FlatMapFunction<String, String>() {
  @Override
  public Iterable<String> call(String s) {

    return Arrays.asList(SPACE.split(s));
  }
});

JavaPairRDD<String, String> ones = words.mapToPair(new PairFunction<String, String, String>() {
  @Override
  public Tuple2<String, String> call(String s) throws OWLOntologyCreationException {
    System.out.println("map:"+s);                
    return new Tuple2<String, String>(s, "thing");
  }
});

JavaPairRDD<String, String> counts = ones.reduceByKey(new Function2<String, String,String>() {    
  @Override
   public String call(String i1, String i2) {
     System.out.println("reduce:"+i1); 
     return i1;    
   }
});

List<Tuple2<String, String>> output = counts.collect();
```

Comment: Can you list the output for  $ cat $SPARK_HOME/conf/slaves file

Answer (score 0):

1) Check `SPARK_HOME/conf/slave` file or the master WebUI whether all the slaves are listed.
2) Which cluste mode are you using?Println might give output in the driver.
3) The RDD may not have enough partitions.
4) Check in the worker UI whether the executors are started while job is executing .
5)increase the default data parallelization and check.